# Assistance troubleshooting google.drive.files.watch web_hook notifications

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apis-explorer

I'm finding the documentation on troubleshooting `google.drive.files.watch` to be sparse - any assistance is appreciated.

First, I'm using a service account role that has had documents & folders in drive explicitly shared with it.  I'm using a free (legacy) Basic Google Suite.

How can I troubleshoot (i.e. see logs) from the Push Notifications to an HTTPS function; or figure out why it isn't working?

I.e.  I've  made an API call; from node.js to drive.files.watch and registered to receive a web_hook push.
I've registered the domain, and verified my service account, i.e. "it /feels/ like it should be working" -- 
i've found very few examples on stackoverflow for anything related to `google.drive.files.watch`

```json
 { 
 kind: 'api#channel',
 id: 'tify-channel-11tyvaPDAgkIUDMPfSMzOZqi1G-YD0aWt-FAUllQhZMc',
 resourceId: 'uJKV6vliOhpZK_f8ZCNVmxzsx1c',
 resourceUri: 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/11tyvaPDAgkIUDMPfSMzOZqi1G-YD0aWt-FAUllQhZMc?acknowledgeAbuse=false&supportsTeamDrives=false&alt=json',
 expiration: '1535699196000' } }
```

When the document is updated, then I think it should send a notification to my lambda URL (registered to a custom verified domain) // I check the logs in AWS Cloudwatch but see no attempts // no record of traffic (and I've verified any request to the webhook url from my browser does appear in logs)

If I try to access the URI in the resourceUri then I'm told I don't have enough API calls.  ;-( 
ex: `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/11tyvaPDAgkIUDMPfSMzOZqi1G-YD0aWt-FAUllQhZMc`
Results in:

```json
{
"error": {
"errors": [
{
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
"code": 403,
"message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

What and how I can /signup/ above is eluding me.
Not sure if it's relevant, but I also can't seem to get drive.changes.list to output any data, not sure if it's because I'm using a service account and so the file changes aren't made inside that account.

When I use google-api-explorer and oauth as myself, make changes to the file `drive.changes.getStartPageToken` + `drive.changes.list` both succeed (HTTP 200 response) but contain no data -- aside from a valid pageToken.

Also - `drive.files.get` also works and returns data so I don't think it's an access control problem to the file itself.

Any help or ideas are appreciated!

Comment: Did you follow the instruction for registering your domain? https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push#registering-your-domain

Comment: I have succeeded in receiving the notification after adding DNS TXT record for Google to validate my domain.